# How do i achieve a subquery in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

i have an SQL statement like this:

```
    SELECT name 
   FROM CUSTOMERS 
   WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID 
         FROM CUSTOMERS 
         WHERE SALARY > 4500)
```

but i am curious as to how i can achieve the same query in MongoDB

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet  i havent tried anything cause i dont know mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do so is using a simple find query with the [$gt (greater than) operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) like this:

```
db.customers.find({salary: {$gt: 4500}}, {name: 1})

// {salary: {$gt: 4500}} will only return customer documents which have a 'customer.salary' that's greater than 4500 ($gt)
// {name: 1} will create a projection with only the name. (you might have to filter the mandatory _id field, if you only want the name, though.)
```

Comment: why does the name in {name:1} have a 1 ?

Comment: Good question, this is just a boolean flag to signalize that the name should be included. 
From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/:


`A projection can explicitly include several fields by setting the <field> to 1 in the projection document. The following operation returns all documents that match the query. In the result set, only the item, status and, by default, the _id fields return in the matching documents.`

There is also documentation on how to suppress the _id field if needed

Comment: so if i am going to use more than one field it would be somthing like this : db.customers.find({salary: {$gt: 4500}}, {name: 1, age: 1})   ???

Comment: No, and yes.

No, you don't have to define a projection. Similar to `SELECT * `, mongodb will by default return the full document, unless you specify a projection.

Yes, you can always define a manual projection on regular queries, including the fields you are looking for.